# Boolean checkbox value

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

My question is about checkbox boolean value.

See the image below (image is of a View where user chooses the "seminar") and my current implementation.

[image: seminar view]

```
//in the model, "Popunjen" is checkbox value which displays if a cert 
//"seminar" is full or not. Value is set mannually on the "admin" page

public bool Popunjen { get; set; }
```

I need a functionality where, if user clicks "Upiši se" (Enroll in eng.) on "Seminar" where "Popunjen" or "Full" is true (for ex. last seminar in list), some sort of error messagge is displayed.

Is this best done on the View code of this page? And what would be the code behind it?

Comment: If your view is built dynamically, I would simply avoid needing to add an error message at all by removing the row of anything that doesn't have space to enroll.

Comment: On the user experience side, it will be more appropriate if you disable or hide or display another text for the Enroll button if Full is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the code of your MVC, I suppose you're building the View from a Controller [HttpGet] and the table rows are populated from DB query. You could check the value of the "Popunjen" and if it's true disable the "Upiši se", something like:

```
    <td>
        @if (item.Popunjen == true)
        {
            // disable "Upiši se"
            // don't show it
        }
        else
        {
            // enable "Upiši se"
        }
    </td>
```